# Get class contained in RLMArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, class, realm

I need to distinguish between **Class1** and **Class2**. Surely I can get first objects and do *isKindOfClass:* but it seems kinda sloppy.

```
@property RLMArray<Class1 *><Class1> *arr1;
@property RLMArray<Class2 *><Class2> *arr2;
```

How do I retrieve the class contained in RLMArray?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the class name held by RLMArray's using its `objectClassName` property:

> The class name (i.e. type) of the RLMObjects contained in this RLMArray.
>
> ```
> @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *_Nonnull objectClassName;
> ```

[Source](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMArray(py)objectClassName)

Comment: So there's no way of getting the Class object? String is ok, but i'd rather check the first object's class.

Comment: `NSClassFromString`?